# When bind is not set, why `this` is not referring to the window object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am wondering why if I modify this line `{this.increaseQty.bind(this)}` to `{this.increaseQty}`, the console prompts **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined** instead of **Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function(…)** ?? If the bind is not set, shouldn't `this` be the window object ?

```
export default class CartItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            qty: props.initialQty,
            total: 0
        };
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        this.recalculateTotal();
    }
    increaseQty() {
        this.setState({qty: this.state.qty + 1}, this.recalculateTotal);
    }
    decreaseQty() {
        let newQty = this.state.qty > 0 ? this.state.qty - 1 : 0;
        this.setState({qty: newQty}, this.recalculateTotal);
    }
    recalculateTotal() {
        this.setState({total: this.state.qty * this.props.price});
    }
    render() {
        return <article className="row large-4">
            <figure className="text-center">
                <p>
                    <img src={this.props.image}/>
                </p>
                <figcaption>
                    <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <p className="large-4 column"><strong>Quantity: {this.state.qty}</strong></p>

            <p className="large-4 column">
                <button onClick={this.increaseQty.bind(this)} className="button success">+</button>
                <button onClick={this.decreaseQty.bind(this)} className="button alert">-</button>
            </p>

            <p className="large-4 column"><strong>Price per item:</strong> ${this.props.price}</p>

            <h3 className="large-12 column text-center">
                Total: ${this.state.total}
            </h3>

        </article>;
    }
}
```

Comment: In ES6 you are in strict mode by default, so this will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't invoke a function as a method (and it is not bound, and you are not using call or apply), then the value of `this` inside the function will be `undefined` IF:

- you are in strict mode
- you are in ES2015 (strict mode is on by default)

Otherwise it will be the global object.

Also, note that some host objects (e.g. `setTimeout`) have their own specific behavior for defining the `this` value used when, for example, callbacks are invoked.